# How can I unscramble a list of words using a HashMap?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, hashmap

I will be given two files which I need to read into my program. One file will be a list of real words, while the other will be a list of those same words out of order. I need to output the scrambled words in alphabetical order with the real words printed next to them, and I need to do this using a Hashmap. My issue is that I can print out the scrambled word and 1 real word next to it, but in some cases there may be more than one real word for each jumbled word.

for example, my program can do this:

cta cat

stpo post

but I need it to be able to do this:

cta cat

stpo post stop

What changes do I need to make to my code to be able to have more than one dictionary word for each scrambled word? Thank you for your help. My code is below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Project5
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        BufferedReader dictionaryList = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( args[0] ) );
        BufferedReader scrambleList = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( args[1] ) );

        HashMap<String, String> dWordMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); 

        while (dictionaryList.ready())
        {
            String word = dictionaryList.readLine();
            dWordMap.put(createKey(word), word);
        }
        dictionaryList.close();

        ArrayList<String> scrambledList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (scrambleList.ready())
        {
            String scrambledWord = scrambleList.readLine();

            scrambledList.add(scrambledWord);
        }
        scrambleList.close();

        Collections.sort(scrambledList);

        for (String words : scrambledList)
        {
            String dictionaryWord = dWordMap.get(createKey(words));
            System.out.println(words + " " + dictionaryWord);
        }

    }   

    private static String createKey(String word)
    {
        char[] characterWord = word.toCharArray(); 
        Arrays.sort(characterWord);
        return new String(characterWord);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Rather than a `Map<String,String>` you will need a `Map<String,List<String>>`.

Comment: you could also use Map<String, HashSet<String>> to disallow repeat real words if they exist in the file

Comment: hint: transforming a `String` into a `Set<Character>` will make it easier to see if two words are anagrams of one another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do several changes. The biggest one is that `dWordMap` can't hold just one `String` - it needs to hold the list of words that are found in the scrambled words file.

The next change is being able to manipulate that list. I've added a sample solution which is untested but should give you a good place to start from.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.*;

public class Projects {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader dictionaryList = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( args[0] ) );
        BufferedReader scrambleList = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( args[1] ) );

        Map<String, List<String>> dWordMap = new HashMap<>();

        while (dictionaryList.ready()) {
            String word = dictionaryList.readLine();
            dWordMap.put(createKey(word), new ArrayList<>());
        }

        dictionaryList.close();

        while (scrambleList.ready()) {
            String scrambledWord = scrambleList.readLine();
            String key = createKey(scrambledWord);
            List<String> list = dWordMap.get(key);
            list.add(scrambledWord);
        }

        scrambleList.close();

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : dWordMap.entrySet()) {
            String word = entry.getKey();
            List<String> words = entry.getValue();
            Collections.sort(words);
            System.out.println(concatList(words, " ") + " " + word );
        }
    }

    private static String createKey(String word) {
        char[] characterWord = word.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(characterWord);
        return new String(characterWord);
    }

    private static String concatList(List<String> list, String delimiter) {
        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(delimiter);
        list.forEach(joiner::add);
        return joiner.toString();
    }
}
```

There a few other changes I would have made - the first is to put the calls to `dictionaryList.close();` and `scrambleList.close();` in a `finally` part of a `try...catch` clause to make sure that the resources are freed in the end no matter what happens. You can also consider using Java 8's [Streams](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/) to make the code more up to date. I'll be happy to give some more tips if this doesn't fit your needs or you have any more questions. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to record the list of dictionary words that are anagrams of each scrambled word then you will need to have a map to a list:

```
Map<String, List<String>> anagrams = new HashMap<>();
```

Then, for each scrambled word, you add a list of dictionary words to the map:

```
anagrams.put(scrambled, allAnagrams(scrambled));
```

Where `allAnagrams` would look like:

```
private List<String> allAnagrams(String scrambled) {
    List<String> anagrams = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String word: dictionary) {
        if (isAnagram(word, scrambled))
            anagrams.add(word);
    }
    Collections.sort(anagrams);
    return anagrams;
}
```

Not that if you have Java 8 and are familiar with streams then this could be:

```
private List<String> allAnagrams(String scrambled) {
    return dictionary.stream()
        .filter(word -> isAnagram(scrambled, word))
        .sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve upon @sprinter's `Map<String, List<String>>` example:

```
private final Map<String, List<String>> lookup = new HashMap<>();

public List<String> getList(String word) {
    //can also make #computeIfAbsent use an "initializer" for the key
    return lookup.computeIfAbsent(word, k -> new ArrayList<>());
}
```

Then it's simple to interact with:

```
List<String> words = getList("tspo"); //spot, post, stop, etc...
```

You can do the unscrambling from there, and could go even further if you wanted to save space and find a way to index the key as a specific list of characters (so that `sotp` and `tpos` would do only one lookup).